# Drawer bottom repair - screw or nail?

Tags: repair, wood, mdf

What is the correct way to repair the bottom of a drawer that has fallen out - screw or nail? Both the bottom sheet of the drawer and the frame seem to be fiberboard. The bottom sheet was originally attached to the frame with staples.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Glue it. nails and screws don't work well in thin composite drawer bottoms.